# jQuery get response from php file after posting

Tags: jquery

I'm posting some data to a php file with jquery. The PHP file just saves the data and prints the success of fail message. I would like to get the message generated by php file and embed in a div. I'm unable to figure out how i can return the message from PHP file.

Here is my code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'post.php',           
            data: {
                email : $('#email').val(),
                url   : $('#url').val(),
                name  : $('#name').val()
            },          
        });     
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
//save data
$message = "saved successfully"
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'post.php',           
            data: {
                email : $('#email').val(),
                url   : $('#url').val(),
                name  : $('#name').val()
            },
            success:function (data) {
                $("#yourdiv").append(data);
            }          
        });     
    });
});
```

This uses the `success` callback of the `ajax` function to return your data back to the page within the `data` parameter. The callback function then appends your data to a div on the page.

You'll also need to -

```
echo $message
```

In your php page to give jQuery some data to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the properties of the ajax method yet?

From the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) site:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Of course, your PHP need to echo something (a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object preferably) that returns to the script.